# MongoDB java connection in Mongodb java driver 3.12.1

Tags: java, mongodb

I have mongodb 4.0 install in my Ubuntu 18.04.
I am using java-mongo-driver 3.12.1
I am uploading my code you can see that i have check different type of connections but it's not working.

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, let me know what you think...

```
package test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        com.mongodb.client.MongoClient client = connectToStandAlone();
        com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("javatest");
        QueryData(db);
    }

    private static com.mongodb.client.MongoClient connectToStandAlone() {
        // STANDALONE STILL REQUIRES HOSTS LIST WITH ONE ELEMENT...

        java.util.ArrayList<com.mongodb.ServerAddress> hosts = new java.util.ArrayList<com.mongodb.ServerAddress>();
        hosts.add(new com.mongodb.ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017));

        com.mongodb.MongoCredential mongoCredential = com.mongodb.MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential("testuser", "admin", "mysecret".toCharArray());

        com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyToClusterSettings(clusterSettingsBuilder -> clusterSettingsBuilder.hosts(hosts))
                .credential(mongoCredential)
                .writeConcern(com.mongodb.WriteConcern.W1)
                .readConcern(com.mongodb.ReadConcern.MAJORITY)
                .readPreference(com.mongodb.ReadPreference.nearest())
                .retryWrites(true)
                .build();

        com.mongodb.client.MongoClient client = com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);

        return client;
    }

    private static void QueryData(com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase db) {
        // DRIVER DOES NOT HAVE collection.findOne().

        com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> collection = db.getCollection("people");
        com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor<org.bson.Document> cursor = collection.find(com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq("testfield", true))
            .sort(new org.bson.Document("review_date", -1))
            .skip(5)
            .limit(20)
            .iterator();

        while(cursor.hasNext()) {
            org.bson.Document document = cursor.next();
            String json = document.toJson();
            System.out.println(json);

            boolean testfieldValue = document.getBoolean("testfield");
            String ssnValue = document.getString("ssn");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. Can you check my answer. What you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution.
I have added more jar files,in total we need (bson-3.12.1.jar, mongodb-driver-core-3.12.1.jar, mongodb-driver-sync-3.12.1.jar, mongodb-driver-sync-3.12.1-javadoc.jar). These are available in [enter link description here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/getting-started/installation/)

Now my code is working fine

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

import org.bson.Document;
import java.util.Arrays;



public class MongoConnection {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {           
        // Create Connection
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        System.out.println("MongoDB connected successfully");

        //Accessing the database 
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("java");
        System.out.println("MongoDB database connection ");

        //Creating a collection 
        database.createCollection("first"); 
        System.out.println("Collection created successfully");

        //Accessing collection
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("first");

        Document document = new Document("name", "Café Con Leche")
                   .append("contact", new Document("phone", "228-555-0149")
                                           .append("email", "cafeconleche@example.com")
                                           .append("location",Arrays.asList(-73.92502, 40.8279556)))
                   .append("stars", 3)
                   .append("categories", Arrays.asList("Bakery", "Coffee", "Pastries"));

        collection.insertOne(document);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: MongoDB driver 3.12.1 is called the 'Uber' driver.  It has the new client and the old client.  It has all the org.bson references.  When using Maven (transitive dependencies) it includes all the functionality of the sync driver as well as legacy.  Please be aware the driver architecture is scheduled to change.  Starting with driver version 4.0 it will no longer be an 'Uber' driver - you will need to explicitly select legacy if that is desired.  Your code is using the newest client - com.mongodb.client.MongoClient - so you don't need to worry about the legacy stuff.

Comment: This is not obvious though, `org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core` is not highlighted in the documentation but you need it too.